# Alert user for duplicate entry to a textbox on userform

Tags: excel, vba, macros, duplicates

I have a userform with a textbox for entering the product name and I would like to alert the user, when a duplicate name is entered. The Values entered in this column will get stored in column A and my column A will have values like Kat-1,kat-2,Amp-0,Pji-4 etc. I tried the code below but it is giving me an duplicate entry message when a 'k' is entered. Essentially, I would like it to check completely for 'Kat-1' and then display a duplicate entry message.

```
  Private Sub txt_BPName_Change()
Dim cel As Variant
Dim myrange As Range
Set myrange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
'myrange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

For Each cel In myrange
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrange, cel) > 1 Then
  MsgBox ("Duplicate Entry")
Exit For
  End If
Next

Dim i As Long
Dim Count As Long
Do
 For i = 1 To Len(txt_BPName.Text)
   Select Case Asc(Mid(txt_BPName.Text, i, 1))
     Case 45, 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122
     'Cells(Row, 1).Select
     ActiveCell.Formula = txt_BPName.Text
     Count = 0
     Case Else
     MsgBox ("Invalid Entry")
 Exit For
     txt_BPName.SetFocus
     Count = 1
End Select
Next
Loop While Count <> 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Try putting the code that checks for duplicate data in a `txt_BPName_Exit` event sub. Then it will only check for duplicated data after the user has completely typed in the data and attempts to tab out or click something else (ie, the textbox loses focus).

Comment: In addition to Tim and Stewbob suggestions, I'd point out that your `For Each cel In myrange` loop is not actually testing if `txt_BPName` TextBox current value is a duplicate of what's in `myrange` range. Rather it's testing if `myrange` has duplicates, which seems not to be useful since `myrange` content should be independent of current textbox value. Finally I'd suggest to have a "total" check of your relevant UserForm controls value upon the user pressing some "GO" button: there you can do crossed checkings and inform the user about all invalid data (if any)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I made the necessary change.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the wrong event for what you need to do.

`txt_BPName_Change()` will run every time the user changes any part of the content of your textbox.

You might be able to make this work with a bunch of conditions in your code, but a better way would be:

`txt_BPName_AfterUpdate()`

The `AfterUpdate` event fires after the focus has left the textbox, so basically after the user is done entering data in it.

Comment: The problem with using the `afterupdate` event is that he cannot `.setfocus` back to the textbox. This is why he needs to use the `exit` event. I think there's an SO thread on this, but I'm not finding anything except [this one](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/491006-visual-basic-applications-afterupdate-setfocus-not-working.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Using an exit event and then setting cancel= true, has solved the problem. With afterUpdate there is an issue with setting focus back into cursor. I am just curious to know about beforeUpdate() event. Will it be useful in this situation?

Comment: Although I see the duplicate entry message at the end of my exit event. There is another problem here, If my column contains Kat-1 already, the current program does not allow input of Kat-2, it thinks this as a duplicate entry. Is it possible to modify this code to make it think like re entry of Kat-1 as duplicate.